# How to prevent mouse pointer following keyboard cursor action while zoom in ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, gnome, compiz, ubuntu-gnome, zooming

Now i am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS desktop

I used to use in previous version of Ubuntu Compiz app as an enhancer and in Ubuntu 18 they decided to get rid of Gnome and move forward to Unity. So, I can't use Compiz any more which I used for Desktop zooming it was an amazing feature for a weak eyes guy like me.

I am using universal access zooming in Ubuntu 18 as an alternative, but it is chaos for example when something is happen in the terminal and many lines run down after each others the focus of the forward screen in the zoomed section is following the flow of the running line in the terminal, so if I watch something or read something simply I can't.

So please any one have a solution for this or even better app or anything that helps?

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances, devices or cloud use use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.   18 != 18.04; they are different products of Ubuntu.

Comment: Unity is available for all releases; `ubuntu-unity-desktop` and was default for a time (last default 17.04; it returned to GNOME for 17.10).  They aren't packaged for *snap* only or 18 systems, only the *deb* based 17.10 & later systems.

Comment: ubuntu 18.04 desktop 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

Download `DconfEditor`.Open it

```
then 
org
then
gnome
then
desktop
then a11y
then
magnifier
then caret tracking

custom value set to none
```

and set `use default value` to off instead of on